# Sum of the first 50 elements of the sum $\sum n a^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

> Find the sum of the first 50 elements in for $x = 1.5$
>   $$\sum_n n x^n$$

Now, if I were to find an infinite convergant sum, I would know what to do, since
$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_nx^n$$
it's enough to differentiate this and perform some numerical manipulations.

However, as I am being asked to find the sum of a certain number of terms, I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: evaluate
$$
x\partial_x\sum_n x^n
$$
Also, as is well known,
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^N x^n = \frac{1-x^{N+1}}{1-x}
$$

Comment: The second part of your answer actually solved my problem, thank you!
What does this symbol $\partial_x$ mean in the first part?

Comment: @Aemilius, its the derivative wrt. x. Are you sure that you only need the second part? In your question the sum to evaluate is not the geometirc series, but $$\sum_{n=0}^{50} \mathbf{n }x^n$$

Comment: @Aemilius or is this a typo?

Comment: How did you come up with the idea to use the sum containing the partial derivative? Intuition?

Comment: Yes, but I can differentiate what you have written and obtain my result, or at least I guess so.

Comment: @Aemilius experience. In statistical mechanics one often needs to evaluate the average energy, where the acceptible energy elvels are distributed wrt. $\exp(-\beta E_n)$ and $E_n = n\epsilon$. It's a standard excercise during lectures :)

Comment: @DhamnekarWinod any $x$ besides 1. Notice that the sum is final.